# Save to a text file is not working

Tags: java, android, save

I want to change the value of specific line in a file, but this lines of code  is not working.

```
public static void saveInt(FileIO files, int Lines, int X) {
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    int LN; //counter
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        files.writeFile(file)));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner ( file );
        LN = 1;
        while  (sc.hasNext() ){
            String currLine = sc.nextLine();

            if ( LN==Lines ){
                currLine = Integer.toString(X);
            } 
           LN +=1;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

No error shown, but i can see my entire data in the file is gone (the file size went to 0.6 kb to 0 kb). 
I checked for save file each the game start, and if it is not found then i run the saveFirstTime() Method , which is working fine (this file is set for pre-default values, each separated by new line).

As the game played, some value would changes, and i write down that value to the file with the method i write above, that method to save integer value. ( i have same method with other type)

Say i want to change the Life value in line 30 , 
i'll use : **saveInt(getFileIO(), 30, Life-1)**
rather than changing particular line i specified, it deleted all the data inside the file.

Comment: In this method you are not writing anything to the file. You never call `out.write(...)`

Comment: please refrain from using tags, i.e `android`, `java` in the title of your questions in the future.

Comment: @Titus  I modified ' if ( LN==Lines ){
                currLine = Integer.toString(X);  out.write(currLine);
            }'   . still same.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I fixed the title.

Comment: have you given write permission from your `AnrdoidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: yeah, i am sure i include `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  because i also have other method saveFirstTime() that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read and write from/to the same file at the same time.

To achieve what you want to do try this:

1) Read all the lines from the file and modify the line that needs to be changed

2) Save all the lines in a list.

3) Write all the lines back to the file.

When you create an output stream the contents of the file will be overwritten (that is if you haven't used a output stream constructor that lets you specify that you want to append data to the file). This is the reason why the file size went from to 0.6 kb to 0 kb.

Comment: Ok, if that's the reason, i will try your suggestion then and back to you for the result. thanks